# Est-ce que "las" est un mot valide après un sujet ?

Tags: grammaire

Dans une traduction VOSTFR, donc faite par des professionnels (*Lucifer S6E6, 49:41*), j'ai pu lire ceci :

[image]

Je sais qu'il est possible d'être las de quelque chose. Ici, c'est lors d'une chanson qu'une personne se demande si quelqu'un d'autre sera présent pour elle.

Est-ce que "la" change de cette manière ? Est-ce valide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deux formes sont possibles:

1. Quand tu seras **là**. (à cet endroit)
2. Quand tu seras **las** (lasse au féminin: fatigué(e), registre soutenu)

À priori, il s'agit donc d'une coquille.